# cx_Freeze - opencv compatibility

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, cx-freeze

I get a `numpy.core.multiarray failed to import` error whenever I try to build an exe file using cx_Freeze.

My system uses the following versions:

> python  3.6.0
>
> opencv  3.3.0
>
> numpy  1.13.1
>
> cx_Freeze  5.0

The code is:

```
import cv2
i=333
print(i)
```

It runs fine (i.e. builds a good exe file) only if I remove the `import cv2` line.

Is there any incompatibility between the four modules I listed?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make this work only after I uninstalled cx_Freeze and installed [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) instead. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If this can help you, I managed to make a working example under Linux using SimpleCV with the following configuration:

> python 2.7.12
>   **SimpleCV 1.3**
>   numpy 1.11.0
>   cx_Freeze 5.1.1

The example code `cv2_example.py` is:

```
import encodings
import cv2
print cv2.__version__
i = 333
print i
```

The setup script `setup.py` is:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {'packages': ['numpy']}

exe = Executable(script='cv2_example.py', base=None)

setup(name='cv2_example',
      version='1.0',
      executables=[exe],
      options={'build_exe': build_exe_options})
```

I guess this example could work also for your configuration with python 3.6.0 and numpy 1.11.0 provided you upgrade cx_Freeze to version 5.1.1.