# cx_Freeze is not detecting cv2

Tags: python, opencv, compiler-errors, cx-freeze

I'm trying to compile a program with cx_Freeze  which requires OpenCV (`cv2`). I use the standard setup.py format for building my EXE.

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("test.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="help",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages": ['cv2']}},
    executables=executables

)
```

cx_Freeze claims that there is no module named `cv2`.

Here's what I've tried:

- 1.) Add full path to `cv2` file.
- 2.) Include `cv2` under the `includes: []` option.

Option number 2.) successfully compiles the program but claims that the `cv2` module is not found. Option 1.) fails to compile because cx_Freeze can't find `cv2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cx_Freeze and OpenCV have some linking/compatibility issues, as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359439/cx-freeze-opencv-compatibility).

Try switching to [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/), or setup a conda environement at your "target" Windows machine.